# Yup validation for loginID with dynamic data type(either email or phone number)

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, formik, yup

I am trying to implement login functionality using Formik and Yup. This is my current schema

```
let loginSchema = yup.object().shape({loginId:
yup
  .string()
  .email("That doesn't look like a valid email")
  .required("This field is required."),password: yup.string().required("This field is required."),});
```

But my loginId can either be a phone number or email. So, how do i add the validation based on the type of field that has been entered in the form. If its an email, trigger validation for email or if its phone number, i want to validate it against a regex.

Answer (score 4):

Input field that accepts both `email` and `phone`:

```
const LoginSchema = yup.object().shape({
   email_or_phone: yup.string()
      .required('Email / Phone is required')
      .test('email_or_phone', 'Email / Phone is invalid', (value) => {
         return validateEmail(value) || validatePhone(parseInt(value ?? '0'));
      }),
   password: yup.string().required()
});

const validateEmail = (email: string | undefined) => {
   return yup.string().email().isValidSync(email)
};

const validatePhone = (phone: number | undefined) => {
   return yup.number().integer().positive().test(
      (phone) => {
        return (phone && phone.toString().length >= 8 && phone.toString().length <= 14) ? true : false;
      }
    ).isValidSync(phone);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Solved **email and PhoneNumber** Validation

```
const loginValidationSchema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().when("isEmail", {
        is: '1',
        then: Yup.string()
            .email("Please enter valid email")
            .required("email cannot be empty"),
        otherwise: Yup.string()
            .required("phonenumber cannot be empty")
            .min(6, 'phonenumber must be at least 6 char'),
    }),
    password: Yup.string()
        .required("Password cannot be empty")
        .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 char'),
});


<Formik
validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
initialValues={{ isEmail: 0, email: '', password: '' }}
onSubmit={}
>
{({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors,
    touched }) => (
    <View>

        <TextInput
            placeholder="ramchandran2897@gmail.com"
            onChangeText={(event)=>{
                        handleChange("email")(event)
                        if(Number(values.phonenumberOrEmail)){
                          handleChange("isEmail")('0')
                        }else{
                          handleChange("isEmail")('1')
                        }
                      }}

            onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
            value={values.email}
            keyBoardType="email-address"
            autoFocus={false}
            returnKeyType='next'
            returnKeyLabel='>'
            onSubmitEditing={() => passwordRef.current?.focus()}
            error={errors.email}
            touched={touched.email}

        />


        <TextInput
            placeholder="****"
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.darkLight}
            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
            onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
            value={values.password}
            secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
            isPassword={true}
            hidePassword={hidePassword}
            setHidePassword={setHidePassword}
            min={6}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            keyboardAppearance='dark'
            onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
            ref={passwordRef}
            error={errors.password}
            touched={touched.password}
        />

        <TextInput
            onChangeText={handleChange('isEmail')}
            keyBoardType='none'
        />
    </View>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically validate your fields, use `when` for the `validationSchema`.
An example from the [documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema).

```
let schema = object({
  isBig: boolean(),
  count: number()
    .when('isBig', {
      is: true, // alternatively: (val) => val == true
      then: yup.number().min(5),
      otherwise: yup.number().min(0),
    })
    .when('$other', (other, schema) => (other === 4 ? schema.max(6) : schema)),
});
```

So in your case you have to craft your `is` statement to decide whether it is an email of a phone number, then you can attach validation accordingly.

Comment: Then how do you capture info from the form? Is this implementation able to validate input from one field as either email or phone?

Comment: With this you can validate one field conditionally based on an another field. If your field act as an emal or a phone field depending on a value of a seperate field you can write conditional validation.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with formik but face the same situation as you face here. I was working with Form Hook. Maybe somehow it will help you or someone.
First of all, add a hidden input after your main input in which the user will add phone or email. On change of that main input, you have to check that if this string contains '@' or not. If it contains @ then make a state and update state with true like this.

```
const onChangeEmailOrPhone = (event) => {
let email = event.target.value.includes('@');
if (email) {
  setIsEmail(true);
} else {
  setIsEmail(false);
}
```

};

and set this state value to the hidden input just like this

```
<TextField
  type="hidden"
  name="isEmailValue"
  inputRef={register}
  value={isEmail}
 />
```

Following should be your validation schema to check weather isEmailValue is true or not, If true then you have to validate for email otherwise for the phone just like this.

```
let loginSchema = yup.object().shape({
emailOrPhone: yup.string().when('isEmailValue', {
  is: 'true',
  then: yup
    .string()
    .email('Please enter valid email')
    .required('This field is required'),
  otherwise: yup
    .string()
    .matches(phoneRegex, 'Please enter valid phone number')
    .required('This field is required'),
})});
```

Following is phoneRegex for your help

```
 const phoneRegex = /^(\+?\d{0,4})?\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{4}\)?)?$/;
```